# How to access .io-config.json file values in Ionic app

Tags: javascript, json, cordova, ionic-framework

The contents of my `.io-config.json` file are as follows

```
{"app_id":"id","api_key":"key","dev_push":bool}
```

I would like to find a way how to access these values in the Javascript code itself. For example:

```
// code
var key = config.get('api_key'); // returns the "api_key" value from .io-config.json
```

On this [page](http://legacy.docs.ionic.io/v1.0/docs/io-config) from the legacy Ionic docs there is a similar method:

```
var settings = new Ionic.IO.Settings();
var app_id = settings.get('app_id');
```

however this does not work as I am using the new Ionic Cloud service. Is there an alternative way to achieve the same as above?

Answer (score -2):

I was able to resolve the issue by importing the config file like so -

```
import config from '../../../ionic.config.json';
```

Then I created a type for it -

```
appVersion: any;

this.appVersion = config.version;
```

Then I was able to use it in the markup

```
<p>{{ appVersion }}</p>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: hello were did you add the import config from '../../../ionic.config.json';   ?